# Adding INCLUDE, LIB and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I am writing a new Makefile and would like to copy my object files in obj/ folder. I tried to add OBJ directory folder but it is not picking up. I am sure I am missing something. For now I moved .o files from src/ folder to obj/ folder after compilation.

Could you please let me know how to add INCLUDES and LIB_INCLUDES in this makefile. As include path is not there in Makefile it is expecting me to specify complete (relative) path in source code while including header file.

Also, I would like to include some external libraries (LD_LIBRARY_PATH) statically in my executable, so how can I specify those in Makefile:

```
APPNAME := MyApp.x
SOURCE_DIR   := ./src
INCLUDE_DIR  := ./include
OBJECT_DIR   := ./obj
BIN_DIR      := ./bin

CC := g++
CCFLAGS := -g -Wall

SRCFILES     := $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.cpp)
INCLUDES     := $(INCLUDE_DIR)
LIB_INCLUDES := $(INCLUDE_DIR)
OBJECTS      := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRCFILES))

all: $(APPNAME)

$(APPNAME): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(APPNAME) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS)
        \mv -f $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.o obj

depend: .depend

.depend: $(SRCFILES)
        rm -f ./.depend
        $(CC) -I$(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS) $^>>./.depend;

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJECTS)

dist-clean: clean
        rm -f *~ .depend

include .depend
```

Created separate thread for this request - lubgr.

Comment: what you doing with last line `include .depend`

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` affects runtime linking.  Perhaps you meant `LD_RUN_PATH`, which specifies directories that `ld` will incorporate into a dynamic object for search in _future_ runtime linking?

Comment: I would not copy or move the objects. Typically you compile to the desired object destination directory. Amongst other issues the directory where the objects were linked from can be stored on the app for use by the debugger.

I would alter the line

$(CC) -I$(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS) $^>>./.depend;

to output using the -o option to the object directory directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for the sake of brevity, I stripped off the `.depend` part and both `clean` targets):

```
APPNAME := MyApp.x
SOURCE_DIR   := src
INCLUDE_DIR  := include
OBJECT_DIR   := obj
BIN_DIR      := bin

CC := g++
CCFLAGS := -g -Wall

SRCFILES     := $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.cpp)
INCLUDES     := $(INCLUDE_DIR)
OBJECTS      := $(SRCFILES:$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o)

all: $(BIN_DIR)/$(APPNAME)

$(BIN_DIR)/$(APPNAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<
```

For further static libraries, you pass them to the linker just like object files, e.g.

```
STATIC_LIBS = lib/libfirst.a lib/libsecond.a

$(BIN_DIR)/$(APPNAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(STATIC_LIBS)
```

This differs when it comes to linking against shared libraries, but as you said your libs are all compiled into static ones, this should work.

Comment: Thank you lubgr. This solution worked for me. I added few more things to Makefile not and all looking good. Thank you very much for your help in this matter.